# The need for the synchronized function when doing write operation to DBMS

Tags: java

In the common DBMS, the read/write operation has been implemented the Lock-system implicitly so that programmer does not necessarily handle this complex locking mechanism.  But why when we write code on the application level, it is common that we still need to use some lock/synchronized function when doing write.

e.g.

> public synchronized writetoDBMS(){
>       SQL statement writing to DBMS }

Comment: Consider using database transactions. `synchronized` is merely an advisory lock *upon a particular object*; the database is an external resource and not necessarily bound to the scope of the `synchronized`. They do different things but, the question isn't very "clear" as to what needs to be done or protected.

Comment: yes it is due to the fact that most of the applications are multi-threaded and most of the threads concurrently updating, inserting deleting records, if you want to manage in your application to manage this behavior, you will write such code to ensure that e.g. two update statements should not execute at the same time, therefore you manually write such code but in my opinion you can use the logic posted by @pst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kit Ho: synchronized keyword before method name just ensures only single thread is executing at a time the enclosed code and also other synchronized methods of same object...so other operations can be read or write operation.
Now why do you see synchronized keyword on some DB related methods?
well for concurrent operations to be handled by Database, you rely isolation level.Read
[Database Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)

Now let us say your DB isolation level is READ UNCOMMITTED and you have methods doing read and write to same table, then u definitely want to synchronize those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using `synchronized` is to lock that particular method/code, so that the other threads will have to wait till the current thread has finished executing the synchronized block of code, meaning the synchronized code cannot be executed by more than one thread at any given instance.
This offers protection only within **your** application.